# How to convert isi date to iso in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am getting the date as

```
data.created = "Wed May 03 2017 15:41:49 GMT 0530(IST)"
```

I want to convert it to 
    regular isi format like

```
 2017-03-12
```

My code,

```
 var created = new Date(data.created);
  created = created.toISOString()
```

Can anyone help me.Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code, what you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Date `$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to get the formatted string.

```
var formatedStr = $filter('date')(new Date(data.created),'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: Thnk you very much Satpal.Excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since your input is URL encoded, first you have to `decodeURIComponent` (which replaces things like `%20` with spaces and so on).

Then convert the result into a `Date` object.

Then use the `getFullYear`, `getMonth` and `getDate` functions to get these data, but don't forget to pad it with `0` (for numbers lower than `10`).

```js
var input = "Wed%20May%2003%202017%2015:41:49%20GMT%200530%20(IST)";

function formatDate(d) {
    var month = (d.getMonth() + 1)
      , day = '' + d.getDate()
      , year = d.getFullYear()
      ;

    month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
    day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
    
    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

var decoded = decodeURIComponent(input);
var inputDate = new Date(decoded);

var output = formatDate(inputDate);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks,Ionica I am using angularjs...so i felt theabove as best.